# Is this signal AC or DC? What are the AC and DC components of the signal?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, digital-logic, signal

[image]

This image is a signal with noise added to it

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Under these circumstances you need to show some effort in solving this yourself. For instance, if the AC part were removed only the DC part would remain <-- what would that value be?

Comment: So what are your definitions for DC and AC? Based on previous similar questions, it is possible that instead of you getting an useful answer, this may just turn into heated debate about definitions of AC and DC, as some people require the current direction to alternate, or voltage polarity to alternate, before they can call it AC.

Comment: DC with a ripple voltage, both for you to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

### It's a trick question ;-)

"AC" and "DC" have two *interpretations*...

1. **The real one**. There are the strict IEEE/SI/ANSI/(et al.) definitions that unambiguously define AC and DC, summarized as: AC = A signal that varies continuously with time at steady-state with an average value of 0; DC = A signal of constant non-zero value at steady-state.
2. **The practical one**. In the real world, a signal you encounter will never by completely DC or completely AC. Real signals are a combination of the two. However, to get things done and communicate succinctly, engineers and technicians will often describe a signal by it's majority component. If a signal is 99% constant with a 1% wiggle in it, we'll call it "DC" even though it's still a combination.

### ...so the answer to whether it's AC or DC? It's BOTH.

The signal in your question can be decomposed into a pure AC signal and a pure DC signal. This may be a homework problem, so I'll leave the decomposition to you. If you get stuck update your question and I'll try to respond in further detail.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more accurately described as a DC voltage with two superimposed AC components.